# Google Play (Issue: Inaccurate Target Audience)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, animate-cc

See This Google Play Mail:-

> Issue: Inaccurate Target Audience We determined that your app and
>   store listing contain elements that appeal primarily to children,
>   therefore the target age groups you’ve selected are inaccurate. For
>   example, your store listing contains elements such as: Young
>   characters. Multiple references to keywords related to children. If
>   your primary target audience is children, you must select the
>   appropriate age groups in the Target Audience and Content section and
>   comply with all Designed for Families Requirements.

**Here Is My Game Screen Shot**

[image: image-1]

[image]

[image]

**I Generate Free Privacy Policy See:-**[Privacy Policy](https://www.termsfeed.com/privacy-policy/88c5268ebda58fd047282cd902bc460a)

** I Select This Target Audience and Content**

the target age group is 5 and under, 6-8, 9-12, and 13-15.

**I trying Changed This Target Audience 5 Times But My App Five Time Rejected. What can I do change in this target audience.**

Answer (score 5):

In the console select your app and go to Store Presence -> App Content -> Target audience and content -> Start.

Select options 3-6 (Aged 5 and under up to 15). Go through the rest of the steps, making sure this is targeting kids.

After finishing this, go to Store Presence -> Content Rating -> Start and make sure your app has the appropriate rating.

Resubmit for review.

Comment: Does this age groups apply as a filter when searching apps in Google Play?

Comment: Make Sure It's up to 12 only.

Comment: Resubmit means uploading again with new version?

Comment: No, when you do any changes in the app listing, at the top right you have the option to Save/resubmit the app. You dont have to upload a new build.

Comment: @leossmith Not found any option as resubmit the app. I performed all changes related to the target audience and save those changes and now under Store Presence -> App Content -> status of all five fields are submitted. Do I need to perform any steps to live my app again on the play store?

Comment: No that should be all. If it takes more than 1-2 days, then try changing some part of the description in the listing and submit.

Comment: @DhavalKansara got app back to playstore without going with new release??how long it takes to get back app to playstore??

Comment: @Sandhiya as *leossmith* mentioned in the above comments there is no need to resubmit the build. Just perform the necessary changes and fill the required information and save. Wait for 1-3 days(max 7 days because of COVID -19) and the play store will automatically make it live again.

Comment: @DhavalKansara hi, i need some help related to this, i want upload one of for kids, but it rejecting everytime with 1. Young characters. 2. Multiple references to keywords related to children.

i have selected all age group under age 3 also and 18+ also.

could you pls help me?

Comment: Here is the solution Please Checkout:- https://actionscript-hindi.blogspot.com/2021/06/google-play-issue-inaccurate-target.html

Answer (score 0):

The App Content field was under Policy for me in the left sidebar. Apparently Google moved it